Supabase RLS not working with custom JWT token
I am creating a custom JWT token using the supabase edge function with the JWT secret provided in the supabase dashboard.
I have all the required claims in the token as per the docs [here, Custom Access Token Hook][1]
(NOTE: I am not using the hooks to add additional data to JWT token)
// Creating the payload

    const accessTokenPayload = {
      aud: "authenticated",
      sub: otpData.id, < ----- user id as per in the auth.users schema
      phone: otpData.phone,
      email: otpData.email,
      role: "authenticated",
      exp: dayjs().add(24, "hour").unix(),
      iat: dayjs().unix(),
      aal: "aal1", // Assuming AAL (Authentication Assurance Level) is set to 1
      session_id: crypto.randomUUID(),
    };

// Signing with the JWT secrete 

    const access_token = await new jose.SignJWT(accessTokenPayload)
      .setProtectedHeader({ alg: "HS256", typ: "JWT" })
      .setIssuedAt()
      .setExpirationTime(jwt_expiry)
      .sign(new TextEncoder().encode(jwt_secret)); < ---- (JWT secret locally dev:  super-secret-jwt-token-with-at-least-32-characters-long)


Using the access token in the client
THIS WORKS ✅
supabase = createClient<Database>(
  process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL || "",
  process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY || "",
  {
    accessToken() {
      const { token } = useUserStore.getState();

      return Promise.resolve(token || "");
    },
  }
);


THIS DOES NOT WORK ❌
const createSupabaseClient = () => {
  const { token } = useUserStore.getState();
  return createClient<Database>(
    process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL || "",
    process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY || "",
    {
      global: {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      },
    }
  );
};

export const supabase = createSupabaseClient();

ERROR MESG WHEN I USE THE ABOVE WAY OF ADDING JWT TO THE SUPABASE CLIENT ☝️

Error fetching all favorite contacts: {"code": "PGRST301", "details": null, "hint": null, "message": "JWSError (CompactDecodeError Invalid number of parts: Expected 3 parts; got 1)"}


I can access tables when the RLS policy is something like this :
[![RLS policy that I canread][2]][2]
but when the policy includes something like this I am not able to access
[![enter image description here][3]][3]
Is there something I am missing out, not sure whats causing the issue
[1]: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-hooks/custom-access-token-hook?queryGroups=language&language=http
[2]: https://i.sstatic.net/eAV1cY7v.png
[3]: https://i.sstatic.net/xFYcMRhi.png

I was making a silly mistake in that the token was undefined, but when I passed in the indented token things worked fine now
For those who are looking for an answer to using a custom JWT token with the Supabse client, you can pass your custom token to the supabse client like this, but make sure you have all the required Required Claims, just like it is provided in the docs here.
supabase = createClient<Database>(
  process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL || "",
  process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY || "",
  {
    accessToken() {
      const { token } = useUserStore.getState();

      return Promise.resolve(token || "");
    },
  }
);

